# Referencing the list rather than the node

Tags: python, linked-list

I'm currently having troubles with my LinkedList functions which are getCount and getIndex which searches through my list, to find either the number given. I am having trouble because my code thinks it is looking through a node rather than the whole list. Here is the error I keep getting.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/koopt_000/Desktop/College/Sophomore Semester 2/Computer Science 231/Chapter4/Test.py", line 16, in <module>
    print(LinkedList.getCount(node1,1))
1
  File "C:\Users\koopt_000\Desktop\College\Sophomore Semester 2\Computer Science 231\Chapter4\LinkedList.py", line 150, in getCount
    node = self.head
AttributeError: 'ListNode' object has no attribute 'head'
```

Here is my code, I have no idea what is different between mine and my classmates could anyone see the problem?

Here is my ListNode class where it creates and the Node and the Links.

```
class ListNode(object):

    def __init__(self, item = None, link = None):

        '''creates a ListNode with the specified data value and link
        post: creates a ListNode with the specified data value and link'''

        self.item = item
        self.link = link
```

Here is my LinkedList class which uses the ListNode class.

```
from ListNode import ListNode

class LinkedList(object):

    #--------------------------------------------------------------

    def __init__(self, seq=()):

        """ Pre: Creates a Linked List
        Post: Creates a list containing the items in the seq=()"""

        if seq == ():

            # If there is no items to be put into the list, then it creates an empty one.
            self.head = None

        else:

            # Creates a node for the first item.
            self.head = ListNode(seq[0], None)

             # If there are remaining items, then they're added while keeping track of the last node.
            last = self.head
            for item in seq[1:]:
                last.link = ListNode(item, None)
                last = last.link

        self.size = len(seq)

    #-------------------------------------------------------------

    def __len__(self):

        '''Pre: Nothing.
           Post: Returns the number of items in the list.'''

        return self.size

    #-------------------------------------------------------------

    def __getitem__(self, position):

        ''' returns the data item at the location position
        Pre: 0 <= position < size
        Post: Returns data item at the specified position.'''

        node = self._find(position)
        return node.item

    #-------------------------------------------------------------

    def __setitem__(self, position, value):

        ''' Sets the data item at the location position to the value.
        Pre: 0 <= position < self.size
        Post: Sets the data item at the specified position to value.'''

        node = self._find(position)
        node.item = value

    #--------------------------------------------------------------

    def __delitem__(self, position):

        ''' Deletes the item at the location position from the list.
        Pre: 0 <= position < self.size
        Post: The item at the specified position is removed from the list.'''

        assert 0 <= position < self.size

        self._delete(position)

    #--------------------------------------------------------------

    def __max__(self):

        ''' Goes through each node and compares what the max is for the linked list.
        Post: Finds the max of the linked list and returns that value.'''

        max_value = self.item
        node = self.link
        while node is not None:
            if node.item > max_value:
                max_value = node.item
            node = node.link
        return max_value

    #--------------------------------------------------------------

    def __min__(self):

        ''' Goes through each node and compares what the min is for the linked list.
        Post: Finds the min of the linked list and returns that value.'''

        min_value = self.item
        node = self.link
        while node is not None:
            if node.item < min_value:
                min_value = node.item
            node = node.link
        return min_value

     #--------------------------------------------------------------

    def getCount(self, youritem):

        ''' This function counts the amount of times a certain item is in the Linked List.'''

        count = 0
        node = self.head

        for i in range(self.size):
            itm = node.item
            if itm is youritem:
                count += 1
            node = node.link
        return count

    #--------------------------------------------------------------

    def getIndex(self, youritem):

        ''' getIndex finds the index of the selected item and returns that value. '''

        node = self.head
        for i in range(self.size):
            itm = node.item
            if itm is youritem:
                 return i
            node = node.item

        raise IndexError
```

I only used a few parts of my LinkedList class, which is not necessary to post because it doesn't change my getIndex or my getCount function.

Here is my test code:

```
from ListNode import ListNode 
from LinkedList import LinkedList

node1 = ListNode(1)
node2 = ListNode(900)
node3 = ListNode(3)
node4 = ListNode(99)
node1.link = node2
node2.link = node3
node3.link = node4



print(LinkedList.__max__(node1))
print(LinkedList.__min__(node1))
print(LinkedList.getIndex(node1,1))
```

Comment: Can you include your `Test.py` too please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the method *unbound, on the class*, while passing in a `ListNode` instance:

```
LinkedList.getCount(node1,1)
```

Now `self` is bound to `node1`, not to a `LinkedList` instance. You need to create an instance and call the method on that instead:

```
linked_list = LinkedList((1, 900, 3, 99))
print(linked_list.getCount(1))
```

I did not need to pass in anything for `self`, as the method is now bound to an instance, `linked_list`.

Note that the class is itself responsible for creating `ListNode` instances, you would *not* normally create those yourself.

Note that your `__min__` and `__max__` methods both assume that `self` is a node, not the linked list class; you want to look at `self.head.item` and `self.head.line` there, not `self.item` and `self.link`:

```
if self.head is None:
    return None  # no maximum in an empty list
max_value = self.head.item
node = self.head.link
```

Comment: I see what you are saying about the count and index, but now about my Max and Min function, I tried changing what you told me to and now I am getting an error at the "if self.head is None:" it is saying that ListNode has no attribute head.

Comment: @Cooper: you still need to call `__max__` and `__min__` on an *instance*. you are making the same mistake as with `getCount()`.

Comment: So what i need to do is print(linked_list.__max__()) ? I'm sorry I probably need to read up on instance variables more because this is my main problem

Comment: @Cooper: yes, that is what you'd do.

Comment: I tried that and nothing comes up when I run the code. It just comes up blank even though I say print.

Comment: @Cooper: sounds like you have a new question. If I take your code and replace the first two lines with my proprosed 4 lines, your `__max__` returns `900` for the sample instance.

Comment: Thanks so much! I actually got my code done except for one part with the help of you! I might post another question in a bit if I cannot get this thing to work.